# C# Service Receiver Program Crashes

Tags: c#, sockets, crash

Hi I am doing socket programming. When the data from the socket, program works properly program the way but remain stuck when the data come. I do not understand why this is happening. "server.receiver" part gets stuck and the program crashes. In addition, it doesn't prompt any error.

C# Code

```
Application.DoEvents();
                string GelenVeri = "";

                System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient server = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(Convert.ToInt32(Port));
                IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 0);
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                data = server.Receive(ref sender);

                server.Close();

                GelenVeri = (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
```

Comment: why are you receiving twice?

Comment: sorry chance my code @AliKazmi

Comment: check now is it crashing?

Comment: check now but same crashing

Comment: `server.Client.setTimeout=3000;` add my code and then working not the crash

Answer (score 0):

use this IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), Port) instead of IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 0)

Comment: this also did not work continuous crashing @AliKazmi